# Query for View with unique entries from Database with repeated entries

Tags: database-design, performance, oracle-11g, query-performance

I have a table with columns of Hotel names, city name and country name (of the respective hotels). I need to create a view of unique entries which will contain city name and country name columns. Any suggestions on how to go about it?
Eg: There may be 100 hotels with city_name = Miami and country_name = USA. The view should however contain only 1 city_name = Miami and country_name = USA.

I figured I'd need a loop to run through the table but still struggling to put together a query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can easily do it with either a group by or distinct but to give you a more specific answer we would need to know which DBMS you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_name, country_name FROM yourtable
```

That takes the list of result rows and returns each one only once, even if it appears in the table multiple times. See "DISTINCT" in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm fro details.

If you also want to know mor information about each row group, like how many hotels exist in each city you can use `GROUP BY` instead:

```
SELECT city_name, country_name, COUNT(1) AS Cnt
  FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY city_name, country_name
```

This again returns each city only once but additionally counts how often it appears in the table. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065777 for more details on that.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d386c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE hotels(name VARCHAR(100),city_name VARCHAR(100),country_name VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel1','Seattle','USA');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel2','Seattle','USA');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel5','Seattle','USA');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel7','Washington','USA');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel8','New York','USA');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel9','New York','USA');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_name,country_name FROM hotels
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d386c/1/0)**:

```
|  CITY_NAME | COUNTRY_NAME |
-----------------------------
|    Seattle |          USA |
| Washington |          USA |
|   New York |          USA |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT city_name,country_name, COUNT(1) cnt
  FROM hotels
 GROUP BY city_name,country_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d386c/1/1)**:

```
|  CITY_NAME | COUNTRY_NAME | CNT |
-----------------------------------
|    Seattle |          USA |   3 |
| Washington |          USA |   1 |
|   New York |          USA |   2 |
```

---

If you want to create a view for each country you can just add a WHERE clause with the country name like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d386c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE hotels(name VARCHAR(100),city_name VARCHAR(100),country_name VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel1','Seattle','USA');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel2','Seattle','USA');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel5','Seattle','USA');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel7','Hamburg','Germany');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel8','Paris','France');

INSERT INTO hotels(name,city_name,country_name)
VALUES('hotel9','Paris','France');


CREATE VIEW US_Hotels 
AS
SELECT city_name,country_name, COUNT(1) cnt
  FROM hotels
 WHERE country_name = 'USA'
 GROUP BY city_name,country_name;


CREATE VIEW Ger_Hotels 
AS
SELECT city_name,country_name, COUNT(1) cnt
  FROM hotels
 WHERE country_name = 'Germany'
 GROUP BY city_name,country_name;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM US_Hotels
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d386c/1/0)**:

```
| CITY_NAME | COUNTRY_NAME | CNT |
----------------------------------
|   Seattle |          USA |   3 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM Ger_Hotels
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d386c/1/1)**:

```
| CITY_NAME | COUNTRY_NAME | CNT |
----------------------------------
|   Hamburg |      Germany |   1 |
```

Comment: What if I wanted to create a view for each country?

Comment: Karan, see my update above.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. To be honest it did make me understand a lot.

Comment: @KaranBhandarkar, glad I could help. Would you mind marking my response as accepted answer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work